# How regular expression OR operator is evaluated

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

In **T-SQL** I have generated [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) using [NEWID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function. For example:

```
723952A7-96C6-421F-961F-80E66A4F29D2
```

Then, all dashes (`-`) are removed and it looks like this:

```
723952A796C6421F961F80E66A4F29D2
```

Now, I need to turn the string above to a valid `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` using the following format `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` and setting the dashes again.

To achieve this, I am using `SQL CLR` implementation of the `C#` `RegexMatches` function with this `^.{8}|.{12}$|.{4}` regular expression which gives me this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[RegexMatches] ('723952A796C6421F961F80E66A4F29D2', '^.{8}|.{12}$|.{4}')
```

[image]

Using the above, I can easily build again a correct `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` but I am wondering  how the `OR` operator is evaluated in the regular expression. For example, the following will not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[RegexMatches] ('723952A796C6421F961F80E66A4F29D2', '^.{8}|.{4}|.{12}$')
```

[image]

Is it sure that the first regular expression will first match the start and the end of the string, then the other values and is always returning the matches in this order (I will have issues if for example, `96C6` is matched after `421F`).

Comment: Also, the reason `^.{8}|.{4}|.{12}$` returns blocks of four instead of the last of 12 is due to the fact that the first `or (|)` value that matches is used, **not** the most-qualified. The regex parser sees the `.{4}` before it sees the `.{12}$`, and as such matches them in quads.

Comment: @EBrown, this situation is part of a complex application. I am not able to change the way how the things are done. Just need to find a way to handle this situation.

Comment: @EBrown, So, it is always matching the `OR` block in a order?

Comment: Yes. The `or (|)` tokens indicate a specific order. I.e. `A|B|C` and `A|C|B` are different Regexes. Also, I would recommend against the `dot (.)` match-all. Instead build a `character class [a-fA-F0-9]` instead.

Comment: If you want to guarantee that it only matches `GUID`-valid strings, I recommend you use the following Regex (or something similar): `^([a-fA-F0-9]{8})([a-fA-F0-9]{4})([a-fA-F0-9]{4})([a-fA-F0-9]{4})([a-fA-F0-9]{12})$` This guarantees that only strings that appear to be valid `GUIDs` can match.

Comment: Why are you using regex to pull this apart? You know exactly where the dashes should be reinserted. E.g. `STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(UnDashedValue,21,0,'-'),17,0,'-'),13,0,'-'),9,0,'-')` does the job.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah, good point... Thanks, I am going to use this instead.

Comment: We must be working with different definitions of clear. I.e. the fact that you're having to ask a question about the regex variant seems to me that it might not be "clear".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in what happens when you use [`|` alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), the answer is easy: the **regex engine processes the expression and the input string from *left* to *right***.

Taking the pattern you have as an example, `^.{8}|.{12}$|.{4}` starts inspecting the input string from the left, and checks for `^.{8}` - first 8 characters. Finds them and it is a match. Then, goes on and finds the last 12 characters with `.{12}$`, and again there is a match. Then, any 4-character strings are matched.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vfVSrMHGDZPJjApt)

Next, you have `^.{8}|.{4}|.{12}$`. The expression is again parsed from left to right, first 8 characters are matched first, **but** next, only 4-character sequences will be matched, `.{12}` won't ever fire because there will be `.{4}` matches!

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4Z8h_4Asi3ccPsDm)

Answer (score 3):

Your Regex `^.{8}|.{12}$|.{4}` evaluates to:

Starting with any character except \n { Exactly 8 times }

OR any character except \n { Exactly 12 times }

OR any character except \n { Exactly 4 times } globally

This means that anything after 4 characters in a row will be matched because somewhere in a string of >4 characters there are 4 characters in a row.

1 [false]

12 [false]

123 [false]

**1234 [true]**

**12345 [true]**

**123456 [true]**

**1234567 [true]**

**12345678 [true]**

**123456789 [true]**

**1234567890 [true]**

**12345678901 [true]**

**123456789012 [true]**

You might be looking for:

`^.{8}$|^.{12}$|^.{4}$`

Which gives you:

1 [false]

12 [false]

123 [false]

**1234 [true]**

12345 [false]

123456 [false]

1234567 [false]

**12345678 [true]**

123456789 [false]

1234567890 [false]

12345678901 [false]

**123456789012 [true]**